# Test data refresh with Prod data

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have aws rds(Oracle and Mysql) hosted on EC2 both in test and prod environment. I want to refresh test data with prod(500+ gb). Can someone suggest faster way to go? I want endpoint should be preserved, minimum cost.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `AWS Database Migration Service`

> AWS Database Migration Service is a web service you can use to migrate data from your database that is on-premises, on an Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) DB instance, or in a database on an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance to a database on an AWS service. These services can include a database on Amazon RDS or a database on an Amazon EC2 instance. You can also migrate a database from an AWS service to an on-premises database. You can migrate data between heterogeneous or homogenous database engines.

You may follow step by step guide [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/DMS-SBS-Welcome.html)

500 gb might be a lot for a test database and also migration will take more time. Here is the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/pricing/)

Comment: This doesn't fit well, what I am doing right now is to take snapshot of prod, mount it to test server and restore the test db. it took long time and manual work. I need something quick and automated very minimal manual work.

Comment: which part doesn't fit well ?

Comment: cost, I have 10 such DB. so I need common approach for all